# How to traverse through the sub directories in gradle task

Tags: build.gradle

im writing a new gradle task. i need to iterate through the root directory and copy files from specific sub directories say xyz to the target folder in project.
sub directories with xyz can be multiple.
so i need to copy files in folders xyz to the target location